# How to fine tune this xgboost model

Tags: r, xgboost

How could I fine tune this so I can get better prediction? I don't know how 
to make it a better model. Any insight will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a 
ton.

Basically I meant to predict best corrected visual acuity (BCVA 0,1 with 
0=20/20 vision, 1=worse than 20/20).

Liyan

```
#preparing data
library(xgboost)
train <- read_sas("Rtrain2.sas7bdat",NULL)
test <- read_sas("Rtest2.sas7bdat",NULL)
labels <- train$bcva01 
test_label <- test$bcva01

#outcome variable
drops <- c("bcva01")
x<-train[ , !(names(train) %in% drops)]
x_test<-test[ , !(names(test) %in% drops)]

new_tr <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = x) 
new_ts <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = x_test)

#preparing matrix 
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_tr,label = labels) 
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_ts,label=test_label)


#parameters

?list
params <- list(booster = "gbtree", objective = "binary:logistic", eta=0.03, 
gamma=0, max_depth=6, 
           min_child_weight=1, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1)


#Using the inbuilt xgb.cv function
xgbcv <- xgb.cv( params = params, data = dtrain, nrounds = 21, nfold = 5, 
showsd = T, stratified = T, print.every.n = 10, early.stop.round = 21, 
maximize = F)

min(xgbcv$test.error.mean) #inf

#first default - model training
xgb1 <- xgb.train (params = params, data = dtrain, nrounds = 21, watchlist = 
list(val=dtest,train=dtrain), 
               print.every.n = 10, early.stop.round = 21, maximize = F , 
eval_metric = "error")

#model prediction
xgbpred <- predict (xgb1,dtest)
cvAUC::AUC(predictions = xgbpred, labels = test[,"bcva01"]) #0.69 2018-10-25
```

Comment: Looks like you may need to tune some of the model parameters, like max_depth, min_child_weight, etc

Comment: Thanks Konvas. I will try these

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to auto calibrate your hyper parameters:

1. scikit-learn GridSearch [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html)
2. Hyperopt which I use, [here](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) with a nice example [here](https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/parameter-tuning-with-hyperopt) and a [short example on how to do it with xgboost](https://www.kaggle.com/dreeux/hyperparameter-tuning-using-hyperopt)
3. Bayesian Optimization with xgboost example [here](https://www.kaggle.com/tilii7/bayesian-optimization-of-xgboost-parameters)

All are technique of finding some kind of "minimum" in a defined "space" where that defined "space" is the "search space" you will define for your hypter parameters and the "minimum" is the models error you'd like to reduce.

Subject is quite wide and you have a lot to read, or you can just follow some examples and implement it in your code.